# Pandas time to hour conversion using Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following data frame, `df`:

```
no.        site_number        date              time  Class  Speed_KPH
0                  11  2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43
1                  11  2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45
2                  11  2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31
3                  11  2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31
```

I wish to create a new column, `time_slot` from the `time` column, such that it gives the end of the given hour.

```
no.        site_number        date              time  Class  Speed_KPH      Hour_slot
    0                  11  2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43    1
    1                  11  2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45    3
    2                  11  2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31    1
    3                  11  2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31    4
```

I defined a function to convert the time into an hour and then used lambda calculus to define a new column, `time_slot`.

```
def time_slot_convert(time):
    return (time.hour()) + 1

df['time_slot'] = df.apply(lambda row: time_slot_convert(row['time']), axis =1)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'hour'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Then you can use [`dt.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.minute.html), not [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html), if `00:00:13.0000000` is `Hours:Minutes:Seconds`:

```
df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.minute + 1
print df
     site_number       date              time  Class  Speed_KPH  time_slot
no.                                                                       
0             11 2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43          1
1             11 2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45          3
2             11 2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31          1
3             11 2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31          4


df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour + 1
print df
     site_number       date              time  Class  Speed_KPH  time_slot
no.                                                                       
0             11 2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43          1
1             11 2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45          1
2             11 2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31          1
3             11 2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31          1
```

If you need `apply` function:

```
def time_slot_convert(time):
    return (time.minute + 1)

df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).apply(time_slot_convert)
print df
     site_number       date              time  Class  Speed_KPH  time_slot
no.                                                                       
0             11 2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43          1
1             11 2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45          3
2             11 2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31          1
3             11 2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31          4
```

Or apply `lambda`:

```
def time_slot_convert(time):
    return (time.minute + 1)

df['time_slot']=df.apply(lambda row: time_slot_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['time'])),axis=1)
print df
     site_number       date              time  Class  Speed_KPH  time_slot
no.                                                                       
0             11 2016-02-27  00:00:13.0000000  Short         43          1
1             11 2016-02-27  00:02:15.0000000  Short         45          3
2             11 2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000  Short         31          1
3             11 2016-02-27  00:03:28.0000000  Short         31          4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
import time
def time_slot_convert(time):
    time = time.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.0000000")
    return time.tm_hour + 1
```